# Implementing and visualizing a binary tree in java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, nodes, graphviz

i had to implement a binary tree pictured on this file

together with the class Diagramm and binary tree for orientation.

[image]

[image]

So following the text and the Pictures i have to implement a constructor, a get- and insert method for this binary tree.

```
public class BinaryTree {

 private Node root = null;

private static class Node {
    private Integer key;
    private String value;
    private Node left = null;
    private Node right = null;

    public Node(Integer key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public boolean insert(Integer key, String value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(key, value);
        return true;
    } else {
        return insert(root, key, value);
    }
}

private boolean insert(Node node, Integer key, String value) {
    if (key.equals(node.key)) {
        // duplicate
        return false;
    } else if (key < node.key) {
        if (node.left == null) {
            node.left = new Node(key, value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return insert(node.left, key, value);
        }
    } else if (key > node.key) {
        if (node.right == null) {
            node.right = new Node(key, value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return insert(node.right, key, value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// not tested, crass assumptions, public domain
public String get(Integer key) {
    return get(root, key); // start search from the root.
}

public String get(Node node, Integer key) {
    String result = null; // Assume key is not found

    if (node.key.equals(key)) { // Key matches? This is the result.
        return node.value;
    } else {
        if (key < node.key && node.left != null) { // key is lower than
                                                    // current node,
                                                    // and there is a left
                                                    // branch, keep
                                                    // search from there.
            result = get(node.left, key);
        } else if (key > node.key && node.right != null) { // key is greater
                                                            // than current
                                                            // node,
                                                            // and there is
                                                            // a left
                                                            // branch,
                                                            // keep search
                                                            // from there.
                                                            // The key >
                                                            // node.key is
                                                            // arguably
                                                            // redundant.
            result = get(node.right, key);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

How can i implement a correct main function for testing? And on top i have to visualize the binary tree with help of [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and adding a method in the node class which creates a string for the dot-code. How does it work with Eclipses?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53366/Binary-Trees-in-Java

Comment: insert looks wrong.  It inserts twice if key < this.key and not at all if >.

Comment: It might be wrong, but man gave it a try!

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method will start at a specific node within the tree, and check whether that node itself meets the criteria. If it does, it returns the value. If not, it will defer to the appropriate branch and continue searching.

```
// not tested, crass assumptions, public domain
public String get(Integer key) {
    return get(root, key); // start search from the root.
}

public String get(Node node, Integer key) {
    String result = null; // Assume key is not found

    if (node.key.equals(key)) { // Key matches? This is the result.
        return node.value;
    } else {
        if (key < node.key && node.left != null) {  // key is lower than current node, 
                                                    // and there is a left branch, keep
                                                    // search from there.
            result = get(node.left, key);
        } else if (key > node.key && node.right != null) {  // key is greater than current node,
                                                            // and there is a left branch,
                                                            // keep search from there.
                                                            // The key > node.key is arguably
                                                            // redundant.
            result = get(node.right, key);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Fails, if *root is null*.

Comment: How would you change the line(s) which leads the fail?

Comment: Frankly, I'm going to leave "if root is null" problem as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose procedural approach, right way to do things will be that:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private Node root = null;

    private static class Node {
        private Integer key;
        private String value;
        private Node left = null;
        private Node right = null;

        public Node(Integer key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public boolean insert(Integer key, String value) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(key, value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return insert(root, key, value);
        }
    }

    private boolean insert(Node node, Integer key, String value) {
        if (key.equals(node.key)) {
            // duplicate
            return false;
        } else if (key < node.key) {
            if (node.left == null) {
                node.left = new Node(key, value);
                return true;
            } else {
                return insert(node.left, key, value);
            }
        } else if (key > node.key) {
            if (node.right == null) {
                node.right = new Node(key, value);
                return true;
            } else {
                return insert(node.right, key, value);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now compare it to OOP approach and choose, which one you like more:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private Node root = null;

    private static class Node {
        private Integer key;
        private String value;
        private Node left = null;
        private Node right = null;

        public Node(Integer key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        private boolean insert(Integer key, String value) {
            if (key.equals(this.key)) {
                // duplicate
                return false;
            } else if (key < this.key) {
                if (left == null) {
                    left = new Node(key, value);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return left.insert(key, value);
                }
            } else if (key > this.key) {
                if (right == null) {
                    right = new Node(key, value);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return right.insert(key, value);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean insert(Integer key, String value) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(key, value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return root.insert(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Solution is simple. For **insert** operation:

1. If there is no root in the tree yet, create one.
2. Otherwise add a new value to the root node.

Inserting a value to some node (starting from root one):

1. If node's key equals to the inserted key => we have a duplicate and won't proceed any further.
2. If inserted key *is lesser than* node's key, do:

   1. If there is no left subtree, create a new node and assign it as a left child.
   2. If there is already a left subtree, recursively add new (key, value) to it.
3. If inserted key *is greater than* node's key, do: (by analogy with #2)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm new on this topic not in Java coding, but it would be nice if you can describe your solution. Maybe with a Little more details for my understanding. And i really dont know what the get-method does or the implementation of the method. I got link above with the topic and read it.

Comment: Alright, i wanna know why u set the left and right node on null at the beginning. Also why they are no right or left in the constructor because a mate said that he wrote a constructor with all variables in it. The reason behind that was to state right and left nodes. And i didnt test the whole code, i got error messages on coding the main function because i use different types(Integer != int ).

Comment: @Evelynn48652 Look. If you create a new *node*, it has both left and right subtrees empty. This is detoted as *null* assigned to left/right fields in the code.

Comment: And why u coded the constructor that way,rest with reason in my question above.